# Insert INTO tableA (...) Values(...) Where id from tableB

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, insert

Basicly I have a table for persons data- tb_person (name,date&time,person_id etc) and other table for meals- tb_meals(meal_id,meal type etc)
, I want to insert a value in meal in tb_meals where person_id(from tb_person)= 1

the problem is that it is ignoring the condition it just inserting in every ids,
there is my code:

```
create table if not exists tb_meal(
meal_id int primary key auto_increment,
meal_type enum("Vegan","Meat","Fish")not null,
meal varchar(100) not null,
price double,
meal_date date not null,
status enum("pending","done") default("pending")
);


create table if not exists tb_person(
person_id int primary key auto_increment,
person_name varchar(100) not null,
office enum("Student","Teacher") not null,
date_order_made DATETIME default now(),
meal_ int,
FOREIGN KEY (meal_) REFERENCES tb_meal(meal_id)
);

insert into tb_pessoas(person_name,office) values("ao","student"),("Tb","Teacher");
INSERT INTO tb_almocos (id_almocos,tipo_almoco,almoco,preco,data_almoco)
SELECT 1,"Carne", "laranajaa",29.30,'2022-03-22'
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb_pessoas WHERE id_pessoas = 1);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: show a [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/vTEgd7v6) with expected results

Comment: Please share your code as text instead of images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen that before, unfortunately keep with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS()` to test if the query of the other table finds anything.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_person (
  person_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_meals (
  meal_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  meal_type VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO tb_person (person_id, name) VALUES (1, 'John Smith');

INSERT INTO tb_meals (meal_id, meal_type)
SELECT 1, 'Dinner'
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb_person WHERE person_id = 1);

INSERT INTO tb_meals
SELECT 2, 'Lunch'
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb_person WHERE person_id = 2);
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bb741)

This will add meal 1 because the `person_id = 1` condition is true, but will not add meal 2 because `person_id = 2` is false.

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same problem the condition is ignored and the values ​​are inserted in all fields

Comment: Can you update the question with sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I just tested this and it worked, so the problem is probably your condition.

Comment: I've added a link to a sqlfiddle demo demonstrating it.

Comment: I updated the question hope is more clear now

Comment: Why did you undo the nice formatting that I added in my edit? I can't read what you wrote.

Comment: You didn't add any sample data.

Comment: I've updated my answer and demo to match your tables.

Comment: it did the insert but it is doing that for all the persons in the database and not only on id=1/2 did you tryed it with more than one person inserted or am I doing something wrong?(I'm new with mysql)

Comment: In my demo, it inserts for 1, but not for 2, because there's no 2 in the person table.

Comment: I think you're not explaining what you want clearly. That's why I keep asking you to show sample data and the expected results.

Comment: I want insert those meal values only in to one person (person_id =1 by example) however when i try it , it inserts those values in persons_id

Comment: You keep saying the same thing. Why do you think I'll understand it any differently? Please show ACTUAL DATA. Edit the question and show the initial contents of the two tables. Then show what you want to be added to the table. See [table markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) for how to format a table in the question.

Comment: I have a feeling your question is related to foreign keys (`person_id` is a FK in the meals table that links to the persons table?), but that isn't obvious from what you've said.

Answer (score 0):

Since `person_id` is the Primary key on `tb_person`, then you can do it using something like this :

```
INSERT INTO tb_meal (col1, col2, col3)
select valA, valB, valC
from tb_person
where person_id = 1
```

`valA`, `valB` and `valC` are values to be inserted

Exemple :

```
INSERT INTO tb_meal (meal_id,meal_type, meal,price,meal_date) 
select 1,"Meat", "laranajaa",29.30,'2022-03-22' 
from tb_person
where person_id = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cZu1M-xt)

Comment: I don't think they want data from the other tables, the data is constant. They just want to use the other table as a condition on whether to insert.

Comment: the values are not in another table, the values are an input from the user, basicly i have a table with data about peapole (person_id..) and other about meals, I wanna insert into meals table (date,meal etc) where person_id(from persons table)=X

Comment: Note that if there are multiple rows in `otherTable` that satisfy the condition, you'll insert that many duplicate rows into `tbl`.

Comment: @cdb I have updated my answer, can you have to look

Comment: @barmar that's correct, then my answer is working only if `tb_person` is unique

Comment: create table if not exists tb_meal(
meal_id int primary key auto_increment,
meal_type enum("Vegan","Meat","Fish")not null,
meal varchar(100) not null,
price double,
meal_date date not null,
status enum("pending","done") default("pending")
);create table if not exists tb_person(
person_id int primary key auto_increment,
person_name varchar(100) not null,
office enum("Student","Teacher") not null,
date_order_made DATETIME default now(),
meal_ int,
FOREIGN KEY (meal_) REFERENCES tb_meal(meal_id)
);
insert into tb_pessoas(person_name,office) values("ao","student"),("Tb","Teacher");

Comment: INSERT INTO tb_almocos (id_almocos,tipo_almoco,almoco,preco,data_almoco)
SELECT 1,"Carne", "laranajaa",29.30,'2022-03-22'
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb_pessoas WHERE id_pessoas = 1);

Comment: thats the code of the tables

Comment: @cdb check my update and demo